# PHP / jQuery > New table row inputs do not submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have the following code working:  http://jsfiddle.net/SzW7q/

Admins will be able to go in and create new howto articles and enter new steps over and over again until a particular task has a full article on how to perform everything.  Everything is working great with add a new row whenever the admin wants but the problem I am running into is that once the form is submitted only the original row is being posted and all of the clones are not.  For example the following tr would post but all of the clones there after would notj

Original row posting:

```
<tr><th>Step to complete</th><td><input type='hidden' name='stepnum1' /><input type='text' name='step_num_text1' style='width: 350px;'/></td></tr>
```

Clones that are not posting:

```
<tr><th>Step to complete</th><td><input type='hidden' name='stepnum2' /><input type='text' name='step_num_text2' style='width: 350px;'/></td></tr>
<tr><th>Step to complete</th><td><input type='hidden' name='stepnum3' /><input type='text' name='step_num_text3' style='width: 350px;'/></td></tr>
```

Can someone tell me why these new rows aren't posting and what I can do about it?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure: are they inside the same `<form>`?

Comment: Double-check the HTML source in your browser to be sure you're inserting the new data *inside* the form. (Chrome does this nicely - F12).

Comment: Based on your fiddle it looks like Chrome at least is interpreting your `<form>` tag as being closed immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your markup as

```
<form method="post">
    <table width="60%" border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' class='tform add_howto' id='add_howto'>
        <tr class='header'>
            <td colspan='2'>Add New HowTo Article</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Article Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='howto_name' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Step to complete</td>
            <td><input type='hidden' name='stepnum1' /><input type='text' name='step_num_text1' style='width: 350px;'/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit HowTo' name='add_howto' class='button' />&nbsp;
</form>

<button id='newRowButton' class='button' style='float: left; padding: 2px 6px; margin-top: 2px;'>Add new step</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SzW7q/1/

I chacked post message:

```
add_howto   Submit HowTo
howto_name  asd
step_num_text1  sdf
step_num_text2  sdf
step_num_text3  sdf
stepnum1    
stepnum2    
stepnum3
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a mess in your HTML code, according to jsfiddle. 
Instead of

```
     <table>
       <form>
       ....
       </table>
    </form>
```

you must have

```
<form>
   <table>
   ...
   </table>
</form>
```

so it's basically just invalid HTML.